# empty Optional with custom descriptive exception

Tags: java, exception, option-type, final

I'm looking for a way to return with empty Optional object information why it is empty and details for further investigation. It will be nice to have exception supplier to be passed to Optional.empty method to specify default exception to be thrown if consumer of the optional expects it not to be empty.
Something like:

```
Optional<File> openFile(String fileName){
    if (!fileExists(fileName)) {
        return Optional.empty(() -> new RuntimeException("file " + fileName + " not found!"));
    }
    return Optinal.of(openFile(fileName));
}

// those calls of the method will throw the RuntimeException with detailed description
File openFile = openFile("notexistingfile.txt").get();
File openFile = openFile("notexistingfile.txt").orElseThrow();
```

I know about orElseThrow with exception supplier, but then it should be done outside of the method for each call.
Is there there viable strategy to do this?

Comment: Yes, obviously you can design your own wrapper around an `Optional` and a `Supplier<Exception>` to provide that functionality. Is anything holding you back?

Comment: Optional was created to avoid this situations. If your method return an Optional it's implicit that it could be empty, since it's Optional!
The consumer of the Optional shouldn't expect a non empty one. The consumer should implement the logic to handle an empty optional.

Comment: 1. to Ole V.V.: since Optional is final I can't extend it.
2. to Ezequiel: I'm ok with the method returning empty, I just want Optional to give me more than 'No value present' by default exception in get() or orThrowException(). The creator of the Optional knows much more about those reasons than consumer.

Comment: Putting an `Optional` inside your object doesn’t require extending the class. Another variant is to build the functionality from the ground up (ignoring the existing `Optional` class), it wouldn’t be too hard either.

Comment: That's why exceptions were invented. They eliminate the need for callers to ask whether the result is a special result value and which kind. When you catch a `FileNotFoundException`, you immediately know what the problem is. Works for a quarter century now. Don't try to turn back time.